# Pygame- Check to see if word is typed

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame, key

I'm creating a typing game, and I want someone to type the word that is displayed, thing is. I don't know how to do it. The words come from  a .txt file, each word is on it's own line. A random number generator generates a number, and the text file is enumerated over, and gets the word in the corresponding slot to the random number. That word is then displayed on the screen. Hopefully that makes sense. Is there a way? More code will be given, if this isn't enough. Here is the code that is used:

```
def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurf = smallFont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurf = medFont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurf = largeFont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "verySmall":
        textSurf = vSmallFont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurf, textSurf.get_rect()


def messageToScreen(msg, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurface, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (display_width/2), (display_height/2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurface, textRect)


def randWord():
    rand = random.randint(0,996)
    fp = open("1.txt")
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == rand:
            line = line.strip()
            messageToScreen(line,black,-200,size = "large")
            for char in line:
                global chars
                chars = []
                chars.append(char)
                print(str(chars))

    fp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to process key events in a main event loop, something like this:

```
triggerNewWord = False
currentWord = "opitit"
uString = u""  # Unicode string

# This is the main loop
while True:

    # 1. Process events and update current state (ie: uString)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
            else:
                uString += event.unicode

    if triggerNewWord:
        triggerNewWord = False      # Some event could change it to True again if you need a new word
        currentWord = randWord()    # This should choose a new work but not draw it
                            # Here you are updating the state, not drawing anything

    # 2. Paint current state
    gameDisplay.fill((160, 160, 160))   # First clean the screen

    # Draw every element

    # The Current word
    messageToScreen(currentWord, black, -100, size = "large")

    # What the user it's typing
    messageToScreen(uString, black, 100, size = "large")

    # 3. Update display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Probably you would like to add some control options, like backspace, you can add more `ifs` in the events loop (1.)